# Getting data from an object array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array (
    [bla123] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [12xye] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

)
```

How can i access this array in php and also get the number of 1,2,3.. etc from it in php.
The logic is to get the rating of a products. the data is fetched from the database completely and then sorted using php.
for eg: 
product1 
one star:1
two star:3 
three star:2
etc... 
somewhat like a star system in flipkart, amazons etc..

Comment: `$arr["bla123"][0]; // 2`

Comment: try to print $array['bla123'][0]

Comment: [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: its completely dynamic i wont be knowing what the values will be

Comment: Did you tried anything by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code:

```
<?php

    $mainArrDat = array('bla123'=>array('Your_Array_Data_Here'),'12xye'=>('Your_Array_Data_Here'));

    foreach( $mainArrDat as $mainArr )
    {
        foreach($mainArr as $nowArr)
        {
         //you can access the data that you require from $nowArr
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: dude can you please look at this one. am really struggling with objects in php [Here is the Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865484/group-array-based-on-key-php)