# Group array based on key

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array that is fetched from my database. This is the result returned.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [productID] => bla123
            [rating] => 2
            [username] => 
            [image] => black-468-sir-corbett-9-400x400-imadxbb7hyhkgvpc.jpeg
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [productID] => 12xye
            [rating] => 4
            [username] => 
            [image] => black-602-unistar-5-400x400-imaeffn5mytbruum.jpeg
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [productID] => bla123
            [rating] => 2
            [username] => 
            [image] => black-468-sir-corbett-9-400x400-imadxbb7hyhkgvpc.jpeg
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [productID] => 12xye
            [rating] => 4
            [username] => 
            [image] => black-602-unistar-5-400x400-imaeffn5mytbruum.jpeg
        )
)
```

I would like to Group this data base on product key. So that I would get a an array with product id and its corresponding values like its images and its rating in an array. This is basically for an rating system, product and its rating.

If the above is not practical, can you please suggest me some way in which I  can display all products with its image and its corresponding rating like one star:1 two star:3 three star:2 etc from the above data.

I tried like this

```
foreach($ratings as $value) {
           $productID = $value->productID;
           if(isset($result[$productID])){
            $result[$productID][] = $value->rating;
           } else {
                 $result[$productID] = array();
            }
        }
```

from the above code I will get

```
Array
(
    [bla123] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [12xye] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

)
```

The problem is I also need to add the image to this, which I am finding really hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code, you will get the result inside of an associated array with the key as the product key. I think that this resolution is less complicated than going to every value of the array, get the object, get the ID and setting a new array with that info.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $array[$row[id]] = $row;
}
```

If you want to use it anyway, then do this

```
foreach ($array as $val) {
    $array_res[$val->id] = $val;
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest me some way in which i  can display all products with its image and its corresponding rating like one star:1 two star:3 three star:2 etc from the above data.

Comment: sure i will help you :) but please post the expected data, i don't get what you try to say